# which functions of a chrome extension are being called

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to understand the code of a chrome extension I did not write. This extension is active the entire time and working in background. So I added console.log('function functionName  run'); to every function.

Now I can see the functions in the console. But when I use the small popup to give the extension some input, there are no functions being called, which I doubt. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging#inspect-popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You need to look into the other console. There is one per chrome tab (dont know if your extension uses those) and theres also one for each background page. Access it from chrome extensions page, usually a background.html link (turn on developer mode)